# Выборка из первых 20 слов - как сделать?

Tags: php

У нас есть текст, оформленный в html теги. Например:

```
<ul>
<li>слова</li>
<li>слова</li>
<li>слова</li>
<li>слова</li>
<li>слова</li>
<li>слова</li>
</ul>
<p><span id="more-172"></span><br />
<img src="http://картинка" alt="картинка" title="картинка" width="100" height="100" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-100" /><br />
слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова.</p>
```

Как сделать выборку из первых 20 слов?
Наработки:
Думаю как-то надо использовать explode. Выборка по пробелам не получится. Например, если там будут двойные пробелы или перевод строки - то уже пойдет ошибка (неправильная работа). Чистый текст получать естественно с помощью strip_tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот рабочий вариант:

```
$words = preg_split("/[\s]+/", "Текст, который нужно разделить.", 21); 
$count = 20;
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$a .= ($words[$i].' ');
}
echo $a;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('~<li>(.*?)</li>~is', $html, $m);
print_r($m);
```

Comment: АХАХАХ, тоже тему почувствовал про 200 символов? тебе [сюда][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/81118/

Comment: Этот вариант будет действовать только для тега li. Оформление текста может быть абсолютно любым. Но уже не важно, сам нашел ответ на свой вопрос.